# SQL SERVER - get data in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where data are stocked like this :

```
student| first_name   | last_name    | age     | 
------------------------------------------------
    A  |   ALEX |  NULL   |   NULL    |  NULL  |  
    A  |   NULL |  BEN    |   NULL    |  NULL  |  
    A  |   NUL  |  NULL   |   NULL    |  10    |  
    B  |   SAM  |  NULL   |   NULL    |  NULL  |  
    B  |   NULL |  NULL   |   NULL    |  15    |
```

Is there a way in SQL Server to get data like this :

```
    student| first_name| last_name    | age     | 
    ------------------------------------------------
        A  |   ALEX    |  BEN         |   10    |   
        B  |   SAM     |  NULL        |   15    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `group by`, on the common column(s), and `max()` for columns with just one value per common column(s)

```
select student, max(first_name) first_name, max(last_name) last_name, max(age) age
from yourtable
group by student
```